# Forcing images to not wrap

Tags: html, css, templates

I can't touch the html theme but I have access to the css files.

```
<div class="photos">
    <img src="a.jpg" alt="" align="left" /> 
    <img src="b.jpg" alt="" align="left" />
    <img src="c.jpg" alt="" align="left" />  //align makes the images wrap
</div>
```

Unfortunately I can't remove align="left" from the images otherwise this CSS snippet would have done the job

```
.photos{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.photos img{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible to make these images line-up horizontally without using the force of a table and only with CSS?
**Many Thank in advance!**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `float: none;` :

```
.photos img{
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: No problem, Mohammad. I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.photos img{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear: both; // clears the floating
}
```

You can check out more about the CSS `clear` property on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_clear.asp).

**EDIT** 
Sorry I misread you. Thought you were trying to stack them. You're right to go with `float: none`, or `clear: right` that would also negate the float. I would probably go with both to play safe on IE's sometime crazy CSS assumptions! ;)